# Traefik + Docker + Django

Tags: django, docker-swarm, traefik

I have a docker swarm with running traefik. Everything works fine for the Most services when i set traefik.port it works perfect.

Except the following:

I have a django app with the service entrypoint in docker: python manage.py runserver the Service does Start and stays alive. But i am Not getting any docker service logs and if i call it with traefik service.domain.de i get an "Bad Gateway". Does someone has a Clou where my  mistake is?

I know that traefic is a http reverse proxy, but is there a Dirty tunneling trick how i can for example connect to a mysql dB via traefik with heidisql from external?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you explain how do you make the deployment? do you have a docker compose file that we can see? is it running in a swarm...?

Comment: i found my mistake, i deployed it via swarm and forgot to put it in the traefik network